# PHP code to send email at time of datepicker w/cronjob

Tags: php, email, datepicker, cron

I've made it this far, unbelievably fast as a beginner but I'm asking for help now.

Situation: User selects date from datepicker. My php sends the mail instantly to the user. The data that is stored in sql is "subject, comments, email, date". This all works for me with no issues.

Now I want cronjob to run php script every 15 minutes or so to see if the current date = date selected from datepicker. The php should send an email to the user on that date with the "subject, comments". I'm thinking my code will be something like: ?

```
$result = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM data');
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) $users[] = $row;

# loop through users and find the ones with today's date = to date selected on datepicker
foreach ($users) {
# take the number of seconds and convert it to number of days
$today = (int)(strtotime(date('c')) / 60 / 60 / 24);
$datepicker = (int)(strtotime($user['signup_date']) / 60 / 60);
if (($today - $signup_day) == 0) {
    send_mail_to($user);
}
```

Again, I'm a total beginner.